# aws - DKIM Signing:waiting on sender verification

Tags: amazon-aws, dkim

I followed [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/easy-dkim.html) doc to setup easy dkim on server. After updating dns server as said in doc `DKIM Verification Status` changed to **verified** but  `DKIM Signing status` still on **waiting on sender verification...** . I dont know what does that mean and how to complete the verification.Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following information, which may be helpful:

> Sender verification refers to the status of the verification of either
>   the domain or the email address that you want to enable DKIM signing
>   for. You cannot enable DKIM signing unless you verified the sender as
>   well.
>
> From the description you provided it looks like you successfully
>   verified the DKIM setup for the domain but you didn't successfully
>   verify the domain itself. You need to add the domain verification
>   record as well to your DNS (the record containing the verification
>   token).
>
> Here is a link for DomainVerification:
>   http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/InitialSetup.DomainVerification.html
>
> Please also note that enabling DKIM signing at domain level doesn't
>   automatically enable it for all the verified email addresses at that
>   domain. You can find a more detailed explanation here:
>   https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=365553&#365553

You can read the full discussion on the AWS forum here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=109709

Comment: From the first paragraph in your first link (may have been updated since 2015): "When you verify an entire domain, you are verifying all email addresses from that domain, so you don't need to verify email addresses from that domain individually."